# Server-side Blazor Validation Not Updating UI

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor component representing a form, that needs to perform some expensive validation before submitting, to ensure the uniqueness of a data point on a server. I tried to use this documentation as inspiration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

It seems like better documentation for this is on the Microsoft documentation roadmap: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17377

My component looks like this:

```
<EditForm Model="@form" OnValidSubmit="@Submit">
    <InputText @bind-Value="form.DataPoint" />
    <ValidationMessage For="() => form.DataPoint" />

    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Form form = new Form();
    private EditContext editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized() 
    {
        editContext = new EditContext(form);
    }

    private async Task Submit()
    {
        var isValid = editContext.Validate() && await ServerValidate(editContext);
        if (isValid) 
        { 
            // do stuff 
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> ServerValidate(EditContext editContext)
    {
        var form = (Form)editContext.Model;
        var validationErrors = new ValidationMessageStore(editContext);
        var isDataPointCollision = await SomeService.CheckUniqueness(form.DataPoint);
        if (isDataPointCollision)
        {
            var field = new FieldIdentifier(form, nameof(Form.DataPoint));
            validationErrors.Add(field, "This data point already exists, please type a different one");
            editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My validation code works properly, detects the collision, and prevents submission of the form. However, the UI does not update as expected with the `<ValidationMessage [...] />` component. No UI update occurs at all, and no validation messages are displayed. I've also tried this component:

```
<ValidationSummary Model="@form" />
```

to no avail.

There are no errors either on the server, or in the client-side JS.

Am I barking up the wrong tree with this approach, or have I missed a connection somewhere? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create (and update) an EditContext that is not attached to the UI Form.

Change the first line to (note: no Model):

```
 <EditForm EditContext="editContext"  OnValidSubmit="Submit">
```

The rest of your code can stay as-is, no need for StateHasChanged() or anything.

On the first docs page you link to, search for `"_editContext"`

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks Henk - I misread the example in the documentation and missed that the form was associated with the edit context, not the model directly.

Answer (score 2):

Call [StateHasChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation#enable-the-submit-button-based-on-form-validation) after validation:

```
    private async Task Submit()
    {
        var isValid = editContext.Validate() && await ServerValidate(editContext);
        if (isValid) 
        { 
            // do stuff 
        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Note: or call it inside `editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged()` if you have access to component there.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, this does not result in any different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Henk's answer is correct.  A couple of additions

1. Add  `<DataAnnotationsValidator />` and `<ValidationSummary />` below `<EditForm>` for individual field validation driven by Model Annotations, and Form summary error messages (above form in addition to on each field) if so desired.
2. Once a message is added to a field (`validationErrors.Add(field, "This data point already exists, please type a different one");`)  The message will persist, and future Submits will be ignored as Invalid.
3. Only `OnInvalidSubmit()` will fire at this point because of the validation error above and its pairing with `OnValidSubmit()`.  The error needs to be cleared for normal processing to proceed.
4. I've only found a brute force way to clear the errors, and that is with a `ClearError()` method to reinitialize `EditContext`:

```
    public void ClearErrors()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(form);
        isSubmitButtonDisabled = false;
        showClearErrors = false;
    }
```

I then wire it into a a button that is displayed when `showClearErrors=true` and disable the Submit button.  If there is a better way to clear the errors, I'm all ears.